# Getting the type of the object inside List inside ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, reflection

I have a DataGrid that is given a List, which can be either of type Foo, Bar, or Baz. Later on, I need to extract that data to save it, and to do so I need to know the type of the object inside the List that was set as ItemsSource. I have tried to use `GetType`, didn't work, trying to do `if(GridType is List<Foo>)` for example produces the following warning:

```
The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Collections.Generic.List<Foo>') type
```

And I couldn't find anything on this error. Searched SO too, couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do? Or even, a better way than simply getting the type directly?

**EDIT:**

Ignoring all the boiler plate code (using etc..)

Assume we have created a DataGrid to later add it to the window

```
public class Foo
{
  public int SomeVar { get; set; }
}

public class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow ()
  {
  List<Foo> Foos = new List<Foo> ();
  Foos.Add (new Foo ());
  Foos.Add (new Foo ());

  DataGrid SomeDataGrid = new DataGrid ();
  SomeDataGrid.ItemsSource = Foos;

  Type DataGridType = SomeDataGrid.ItemsSource.GetType ();
  if (DataGridType is List<Foo>) //< Error 
    {
    // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `GridType` here? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...

Comment: Added an example that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two things - `is` to check whether an *object* is of the given type, and `GetType()` which returns the `Type` reference. The type of `DataGridType` is `Type`, and a `Type` object is never an instance of `List<Foo>`. (Imagine casting `DataGridType` to `List<Foo>` - what would that mean?)

You want either:

```
if (DataGridType == typeof(List<Foo>))
```

... which will check whether the type is *exactly* `List<Foo>` or:

```
if (DataGridType.ItemsSource is List<Foo>)
```

... which will check whether the type is *assignable to* `List<Foo>`.

Alternatively, if you would be casting in the `if` body:

```
List<Foo> listFoo = DataGridType.ItemsSource as List<Foo>;
if (listFoo != null)
{
    // Use listFoo
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using typeof:

```
if(GridType == typeof(List<Foo>))
```